# ASP.NET Core AJAX POST not returning error, however, not saving data

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am using a button OnClick event to try and save a record to a database using AJAX in ASP.NET Core.  The function is not returning an error, however, the data is not being saved. I am just trying to test with hard coded data first.  A record with AdapollingProjectProcessStatusId = 1 exists in the database.

```
function SendHtmlEditorValueToController(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AJAXPost", "LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatus")',
        contentType: "application/json", 
        data: JSON.stringify({ "id": 1, "status": 'test'}),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: () => {
          console.log("value is sent");
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });


}
```

**LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatusController:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AJAXPost(int id, string status)
    {
        LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatus processstatus = new LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatus
        {
            AdapollingProjectProcessStatusId = id,
            AdapollingProjectProcessStatus = status
        };

        //save it in database
        return Json(processstatus);
    }
```

**LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatus.cs:**

```
    namespace CPSPMO.Models.PMO
    {
        public partial class LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatus
        {
            public int AdapollingProjectProcessStatusId { get; set; }
            public string AdapollingProjectProcessStatus { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you are able to help me with this AJAX Post.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code that should save in the database? `return Json(processstatus);` is not saving, it just returns a response to the ajax request.

Comment: Hi @Chris, does it hit your conroller? Did you able to check in browser console  if there is any error?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos  this is my first time using AJAX.  I am not sure what the code is to save to the database.  Typically I would use await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok();

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron the AJAX post does hit the controller, and no error is displayed. Console does indicate "value is sent".  However, the data is not being saved to the database.  This is my first time using AJAX.

Comment: That is what you have to do here as well. Use the DbContext to save the object to the database. Doesn't matter if you are calling the endpoint using ajax.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos after reviewing your comment that the code for saving was missing.  I modified the controller and added 2 lines to save the data:              

//save it in database
            var result = _context.LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatuses.Update(processstatus);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(processstatus);

It is now saving to the database!  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the comments regarding missing code for saving the data in the database, I modified the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AJAXPost(int id, string status)
    {
        LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatus processstatus = new LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatus
        {
            AdapollingProjectProcessStatusId = id,
            AdapollingProjectProcessStatus = status
        };

        //save it in database
        var result = _context.LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatuses.Update(processstatus);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Json(processstatus);
    }
```

It is saving the data to the database now.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you store it to the database, but the way you pass parameter to backend by ajax should be like below:

```
function SendHtmlEditorValueToController(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("AJAXPost", "LiveAdapollingProjectProcessStatus")',
        //contentType: "application/json",      //remove this... 
        data:{ "id": 1, "status": 'test'},      //modify here...
        dataType: 'json',
        success: () => {
            console.log("value is sent");
        },
        error: (error) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I modified the code as suggested, I am still not getting an error.  However, the database did not update.   But I will keep the modifications that you suggested.